# Pandas pd.DataFrame from loop-data

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I have some data that I get from a loop. `cat` and be between two and `n` and `TorF` will always be (`cat*5`) or (`cat*4`). My gold is to create a `pd.DataFrame` from two lists, like this

```
cat = ['a', 'b'] 
TorF = [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True]
```

I think my current solution is kind of clumpy with the `int((len(man_corr_n)/len(cat)))`,

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[c, *TorF[i:i+int((len(TorF )/len(cat)))]] for i, c in enumerate(cat)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

if there a simpler way to do it?

My desired output is

```
   0     1     2      3      4      5
0  a  True  True   False  False   True
1  b  True  False  True   False   True
```

Comment: what is `man_corr_n`

Comment: What's `man_corr_n`? Is it a typo for `TorF`? What do you want to get as a result? (in human words)

Comment: @MariaKozlova, yes. I am sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the ratio of the two shapes is a good strategy.

I would however use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

cat = ['a', 'b']
man_corr_n = [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True]

df = pd.DataFrame(swv(man_corr_n, len(man_corr_n)//len(cat))[:len(cat)],
                  index=cat).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
view = swv(man_corr_n, len(man_corr_n)//len(cat))[:len(cat)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.array(cat)[:,None], view]))
```

Output:

```
   0     1     2      3      4      5
0  a  True  True   True  False  False
1  b  True  True  False  False   True
```

#### edit: ambiguous output

Your provided code and the shown expected output clearly conflict. Using an unambiguous input (`TorF = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`), your code gives:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  0  1  2  3  4
1  b  1  2  3  4  5
```

While your expected output seems to be:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  0  2  4  6  8
1  b  1  3  5  7  9
```

In such case, you just need to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.r_[cat, TorF], (len(cat), -1), order='F'))

# or
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([list(map(list, cat)), np.reshape(TorF, (len(cat), -1), order='F')]))
```

Output:

```
   0     1      2      3      4     5
0  a  True   True  False  False  True
1  b  True  False   True  False  True
```

Comment: I've added a desired output. I might make it clearer what I am looking for.

Comment: @EricFail using `man_corr_n = list(range(10))` would be even less ambiguous ;)

Comment: I should have been clearer in mu comment above. The output in your answer does not match the desired output in my question.

Comment: @Eric but your current "clunky" solution doesn't give the shown output. By clunky did you mean that it's not "pretty" or that it doesn't work? The way you phrased it seemed to indicate that the code it functional. Please provide the output for `TorF = list(range(10))` to avoid ambiguity on the repeated True/False.

Comment: From the show output, it could indeed just be a reshaping problem: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([list(map(list, cat)), np.reshape(TorF, (len(cat), -1), order='F')]))`

Answer (score 2):

You could form a Numpy array from the two Lists, reshape, transpose and form the DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cat = ['a', 'b']
TorF = [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True]
TorF = np.array(cat + TorF)
TorF2 = TorF.reshape(len(TorF)//2, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(TorF2.T)
```

giving:

```
   0     1      2      3      4     5
0  a  True   True  False  False  True
1  b  True  False   True  False  True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame({'cat':cat*int(len(TorF)/2),'TorF':TorF})\
    .assign(col1=lambda dd:dd.index//2)\
    .set_index(['col1','cat'])\
    .unstack().T\
    .reset_index(level=1).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   0     1      2      3      4     5
0  a  True   True  False  False  True
1  b  True  False   True  False  True
```